# Error post data using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-post, postman

I'm a new php programmer using codeigniter framework.

I've a problem with post data,
The problem is,
When i post data using url params in postman,
my value(name,username,and email) got false.
and in DB the value is 0

but when i try using form-data in postman, the value is success post and nothing error/false.

here's the json response:

```
{
  "name": false,
  "username": false,
  "email": false,
  "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
  "created_at": "2015-03-30 15:36:58",
  "updated_at": "2015-03-30 15:36:58",
  "status": 0
}
```

and this is what my controller look like.

```
public function user_post()
{

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
  $datestring ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
  $time       =time();
  $datetime   =mdate($datestring, $time);

  $user = array (
        'name'       => $this->post('name'),
        'username'   => $this->post('username'),
        'email'      => $this->post('email'),
        'password'   => sha1($this->post('password')),
        'created_at' => $datetime,
        'updated_at' => $datetime,
        'status'     => 0
  );

  $result = $this->signup_model->registration_insert($user);
  if ($result) {
    $this->send_new_password_email($user);
    $this->response($user, 200);
  } else {
    $this->response(array('error' => 'missing paramaters'), 404);
  }

}
```

and my model is like this:

```
public function registration_insert($data) {

$condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' OR " . "email =" ."'" . $data['email'] . "'" ;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
  $this->db->insert('table', $data);
  if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }
}
```

thank you guys,
CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeIgniter, to get post value use

```
$this->input->post(); //work as $_POST
$this->input->get(); //work as $_GET
$this->input->get_post(); //work as $_REQUEST
```

as i can see you are using wrong syntax.